# wkhtmltopdf goes extremely slow on different environment

Tags: pdf, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, centos7, wkhtmltopdf

I am developing a PHP web application with CakePHP 3.4 framework, and i am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 to output dynamic content in a .pdf file. Currently i'm using three different environments where i develop and test my application:

1. In my local environment (XAMPP 32-bit for Windows), wkhtmltopdf works great. It takes ~1 second in rendering .pdf files
2. In a remote testing environment (CentOS 7 64-bit using apache2, 4GB memory), works great too.
3. In my third remote testing environment (Another CentOS 7 64-bit distro with similar CPU specs as the second one and 4GB memory), wkhtmltopdf takes up to 20 seconds in rendering the same .pdf file

What could be causing this behavior in the third environment? How can i monitor or debug wkhtmltopdf process to help me identify why .pdf rendering is so slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove rgba and set border-radius to 1px in your CSS files (or completely remove them if they are not needed). That should speed up the PDF generation process.

[Similar issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170882#c15)

Answer (score 1):

Another reson can be your current default printer on windows. See:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4891

If you use a standard printer that is

- a network printer
- you use the windows default driver for that printer and have not installed the manufactors printer driver

-> wkhtmltopdf is really slow